# How to get accuracy during/after training for Huggingface RobertaForMaskedLM model?

Tags: python, keras, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using HuggingFace `Trainer` to train a Roberta Masked LM. I am passing the following function for `compute_metrics` as other discussion threads suggest:

```py
metric = load_metric("accuracy")

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)
```

I am loading my dataset from text files using `load_dataset`, and after applying a tokenizer, it returns `attention_id`, `input_ids` but no `labels`. I am training on this dataset using `Trainer`. Still, I cannot find the accuracy of my model during training after passing the `compute_metrics` function above or cannot evaluate my model after training on test data.
How to get accuracy for this model during training and evaluate it as we could do in `Keras` models using `model.evaluate()`? How is it measured?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the example scripts, have you checked the --evaluation_strategy parameter? The default value is None, but it can be set to steps or epoch.